# Does the MP-APS stop Gunship cannon rounds?

Tags: battlefield-4

Yesterday I was playing Naval strike and attempting to capture D objective on one of the maps that granted the gunship ability as their commander was spawnining them in as fast as possible. I got the flag neutralized but the gunship locked onto me and killed me on both attempts to capture it. Does the MP-APS protect against AC-130 cannon rounds or does it not have any effect? Could I drop a MP-APS down and hide behind it or does the protection angle not reach high enough?

Comment: I read somewhere, that MP-APS destroy mortar shells, so it could probably destroy 120mm and 40mm rounds, but i don`t think it will stop minigun rounds. Also protection time is brief and if AC-130 is spotted you, it will get you.

Answer (score 1):

> MP-APS destroys any explosive and shell, no matter if coming from inf or vehicles.

The AC-130 is a vehicle and the cannon rounds are explosives. I guess it doesn't protect against minigunfire from gunship, however this would not be usefull because it only blocks the first shot and has a high cooldown after that.

Comment: Except for grenades. The MP-APS will not stop grenades.